# knife softlayer command throws ERROR: Excon::Error::Socket: Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET

Tags: sockets, ssh, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, knife

Chef Server Version : chef-server 12.11.1

```
knife softlayer server create  
--image-id ${image_id}  
--ssh-keys ${ssh_keys}  
--hostname $node_name  
--network-interface-speed 100  
--domain $domain_name  
--cores ${cores}  
--ram ${ram}  
--datacenter ${datacenter}  
--node-name $node_name  
--vlan $public_vlan  
--private-vlan $private_vlan  
--use-private-network  
-x root  
-i $USER_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa  -VV
```

Client Output

Launching SoftLayer VM, this may take a few minutes.

............................................................................

............................................................................

................

After 6 minutes it throws this error

ERROR: Excon::Error::Socket: Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
ERROR: Excon::Error::Socket: Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)

Comment: Can you please update the output/error log with debug option?

Comment: how do i set debug option for knife softlayer command?

Comment: Add '-VV' at the end of your knife command

Comment: I think for some reason bootstrap of chef node fails. and reason could VM is not created. But i thought knife command should wait until the VM is ready and start bootstrap of node. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, knife was waiting for the VM to create which never came up hence the error. Did you checked if the instance was launched ever?

Comment: yes. there was delay for VM creation. But apparently, we had increased timeout of knife command to 15 mins. we configured timeout in this file /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.42.0/lib/fog/core/wait_for_defaults.rb. And we found this error after 6 mins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144620/discussion-between-mrigesh-priyadarshi-and-dixon-almeida).

Answer (score 1):

The Softlayer's API has this issue where sometimes the server resets the connection to the client. Currently they are working on a fix but there is not an ETA. The issue showed up long time ago. I only can recommend to try catch the error and try again.

Comment: Thank you. Kindly let me know once the issue is resolved.